# No errors but alert dialog not displaying

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-context

I have non-activity class `MenuHandler` to handle menu-related events,
I am trying to display developers message in alert dialog box, this message fetch from `firebase` real time database.

Everything is fine but alert dialog not displaying, I try debugger to check there any error in database but I got value properly from database. No Error to get value from database.

when I select menu from `MainActivity`, `developerMessage` toast shows then nothing happened.

I pass `context` to `MenuHandler` class properly.
Can I Show `Alerdialog` in using context?
or I need to write code only in `MainActivity` only(i.e. only activity class).

**Code:**

```
 public void developersMessage()
    {

        if (isInternetOn()) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Loading message please wait",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            mDatabase.child("version_1_0").child("dev").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        try {

                            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                            builder.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.welcome_msg));
                            builder.setMessage(dataSnapshot.child("dev_msg").getValue(String.class));
                            builder.setPositiveButton("ok",null);

                            builder.create().show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"please turn on internet ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try creating an instance of `AlertDialog` in place of `builder.create().show();` like this:

`AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();`
`dialog.show();`

Comment: nothing changed. result is same

Comment: at the `try ... catch;` level are you able to get debug logs or a toast? Cos if you're then the problem lies with the alert dialog, if you can't then move your debug a level up to the `listener` etc...

Comment: yes in try catch I can debug, but after builder.creat.show() debugger show notting and noting in catch blok also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,
There nothing wrong in the code but bug lies in how I send context from mainactivity

here I wrongly init Menuhandler class

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 final MenuHandler mMenuHandler = new MenuHandler(this.getApplicationContext());//bug lies here
```

if we are showing alertdialog then we need this way to pass context so our alertdialog display properly

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final MenuHandler mMenuHandler = new MenuHandler(MainActivity.this);//this is right way to pass context
```

hope this is helpful to someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Build your AlertDialog out of

```
mDatabase.child("version_1_0").child("dev").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
```

The `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)` method runs on a different background thread, so the UI can't be updated inside off UI thread. Thus building your AlertDailog out of the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)` method should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use activity context to create AlertDialog.

And please debug to make sure `onDataChange()` is called

Also try with runOnUiThread: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

`yourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {... code to create & show dialog ...} })`

Comment: onDatachange is working. My MainActivity and MenuHandeler class is different,

Comment: So try to pass activity reference to MenuHandler. Use it to runOnUiThread and create dialog